# Why does the subdomain finder stop because "label empty or too long"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I made this subdomain finder from a hacking course. It seems to work fine for a little bit but then gives a weird error. Could anyone help me?

Here is the code

```
        import requests

        url = "youtube.com"

        def request(url):
            try:
                return requests.get("http://" + url, timeout=2)
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                pass
            except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
                print('INVALID:', url)

        with open("/home/kali/PycharmProjects/websitesub/subdomains-wodlist.txt", "r") as wordlist_file:
            for line in wordlist_file:
                word = line.strip()
                test_url = word + "." + url
                response = request(test_url)
                if response:
                    print("Discovered SUBDOM" + test_url)
```

here is the output I am getting, as we can see it finds a few websites then stops:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image with the stacktrace, last subdomains tested are:

- `pl`,
- `es`.

And then, the interesting part is at the end of the stackatrace:

```
failed to parse m..youtube.com
```

It seems that the word that failed is ending with a dot `m.` and thus the tried url is `m..youtube` and there is nothing between the two dots, leading to the error you get.

Comment: i read it wrong, that cant be the case because es and pl are 35 or so  words apart, and es is followed by
"n
widgets
es
www90
s269
s281
s216
s221
s222
s224
s227
s233
s236
s237"